# Flutter: pie_chart plugin animation scrolling problem

Tags: flutter, animation, pie-chart

I have this pie chart created by Flutter pie_chart plugin.

```
    return SizedBox(
            height: 150.0,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                PieChart(
                  baseChartColor: AmbarColors.greyNoEvents,
                  totalValue: hoursSpent,
                  dataMap: dataMap,
                  // degreeOptions: const DegreeOptions(totalDegrees: 360, initialAngle: 0),
                  animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                  chartLegendSpacing: 22,
                  chartRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.2,
                  colorList: const [AmbarColors.backgroundGreen],
                  initialAngleInDegree: 0,
                  chartType: ChartType.ring,
                  ringStrokeWidth: 17,
                  centerText: '$percent%',
                  centerTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontFamily: Fonts.satoshi,
                      fontSize: 30),
                  legendOptions: const LegendOptions(
                    showLegends: false,
                  ),

                  chartValuesOptions: const ChartValuesOptions(
                    showChartValueBackground: false,
                    showChartValues: false,
                    showChartValuesInPercentage: true,
                  ),
                  gradientList: gradientList,
                  // gradientList: ---To add gradient colors---
                  // emptyColorGradient: ---Empty Color gradient---
                )
              ],
            ));
      }
```

The problem is when I put the chart into a scrolling area. This is the result:

The chart rotates every time I move the mouse and I don't understand why.

[image: Video of this issue]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have put **SingleChildScrollView** with never scrollable physics. This must be a bug in the plugin.

```
    return SizedBox(
              height: 180.0,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  SingleChildScrollView( //<!------in this point
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    child: PieChart(
                      baseChartColor: Colors.greyNoEvents,
                      totalValue: hoursSpent,
                      dataMap: dataMap,
                      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                      chartLegendSpacing: 22,
                      chartRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.2,
                      colorList: const [Colors.backgroundGreen],
                      initialAngleInDegree: 0,
                      chartType: ChartType.ring,
                      ringStrokeWidth: 17,
                      centerText: '$subsPercent%',
                      centerTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: Fonts.satoshi,
                          fontSize: 30),
                      legendOptions: const LegendOptions(
                        showLegends: false,
                      ),

                      chartValuesOptions: const ChartValuesOptions(
                        showChartValueBackground: false,
                        showChartValues: false,
                        showChartValuesInPercentage: true,
                      ),
                      gradientList: gradientList,
                      // gradientList: ---To add gradient colors---
                      // emptyColorGradient: ---Empty Color gradient---
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: Good catch, well done.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is caused by a conflict between the scrolling event and the animation of the pie chart. The chart is probably receiving and reacting to these scroll events.

As a workaround/test, you could try and block the propagation of scroll events to the chart.
If you only need to display the chart and users do not need to interact with it, you could try wrapping the chart widget with an [`IgnorePointer` widget](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-ignorepointer-widget/). This will prevent the chart from receiving pointer events:

```dart
return SizedBox(
  height: 150.0,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      IgnorePointer(
        child: PieChart(
          // Your PieChart properties...
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

If you do need the user to be able to interact with the chart (for example, if there are interactive elements on the chart like clickable legends), then you might need a different solution.

---

As commented, in this plugin, IgnorePointer doesn't seem to work.

The OP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76388687/6309) points to using a workaround by wrapping the `PieChart` with a `SingleChildScrollView` that has its scrolling physics set to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`.

A [`SingleChildScrollView` in Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) is a widget that can contain a single box and allows it to scroll. This can be useful when you have content that may exceed the screen size and you want to allow the user to scroll to see it. However, it also has properties that control how the scrolling behaves.

The [`NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html) is a type of [`ScrollPhysics`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics-class.html) that prevents the scroll view from being scrolled via user interaction.

So, the OP essentially wrapped their `PieChart` in a scroll view that ca not be scrolled. This seems to have prevented the chart from rotating when it is in a scrolling area, suggesting that there may be a bug in the `pie_chart` plugin that causes unexpected behavior when it is placed in a scrollable context.

So, `SingleChildScrollView` is used to wrap the `PieChart`, and `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` is passed to its `physics` property, effectively making the `PieChart` non-scrollable and preventing the undesired rotation behavior.

Comment: In this plugin, IgnorePointer doesn't seem to work, but it's good information for upcoming issues

Comment: @rafa_pe I have edited the answer to explain why your workaround is working.